# How to send a html / html5 template email with php?

Tags: php, email, templates

I want to send a html / html5 email with PHP. I have a html template with the email message which I am planning to send to a user.

**HTML template** - *default-message.php*

```
<?php include 'mailservice.php'; ?>
<div> 

  <h3>Dear <?php echo $name; ?>,</h3>

  <p>I send you this custom message!!</p>

</div>
```

**PHP** - *mailservice.php*

```
/* getting the content from te default-message.html file*/
ob_start(); 
include('default-message.php'); 
$message = ob_get_contents(); 
ob_end_clean();  

$name = "John"; 
$to = "sadas@yahoo.com";
$subject = "Hello";

$headers .= 'From: Me <abc@mysite.com>' . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: What specific issue are you having?

Comment: It looks like you have created a circular `include`.

Comment: @Blake the email is not getting sent, if I change the extension file to .html, the email is getting sent, but the variable $name is not compiled, I m new to PHP ...

Comment: The email sends when you use a .html extension for your template because the PHP code is not executed. (If you view the source of the received message, you will see the PHP code.) If it _was_ executed, it would cause a `Fatal error: Maximum function nesting` because of the circular include.

Comment: @Don'tPanic thank you sir !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the variables **before** you include the template script, so they'll be expanded when the template runs.

```
ob_start(); 
$name = "John"; 
$to = "sadas@yahoo.com";
include('default-message.html'); 
$message = ob_get_contents(); 
ob_end_clean();  

$subject = "Hello";

$headers .= 'From: Me <abc@mysite.com>' . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Also, `default-message.html` should not contain `<?php include 'mailservice.php'; ?>`, because then it will go back and forth with each script including the other.